# shift matrix elements in R

Tags: r, matrix

```
n <- 5
a <- matrix(c(1:n**2),nrow = n, byrow = T)
```

output is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
[3,]   11   12   13   14   15
[4,]   16   17   18   19   20
[5,]   21   22   23   24   25
```

how do I shift the '1' to the current position of '25' to look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    7    8    9   10   11
[3,]   12   13   14   15   16
[4,]   17   18   19   20   21
[5,]   22   23   24   25    1
```

Comment: `matrix(c(2:n**2, 1), nrow = n, byrow = T)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
a <- t(a); a[] <- c(a[-1], a[1]); a <- t(a)
a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    3    4    5    6
# [2,]    7    8    9   10   11
# [3,]   12   13   14   15   16
# [4,]   17   18   19   20   21
# [5,]   22   23   24   25    1
```

- `c(a)` unwinds or unlists the matrix into a vector. It does this column-first, so `c(a)` results in  `[1]  1  6 11 16 21  2 ...`. We want it to be row-first, though, so
- `t(a)` transposes it, so that what *was* a row-first is now column-first, allowing `c(a)` and such to work.
- `c(a[-1], a[1])` is just *"concatenate all except the first with the first"*, the classic way to put the first element of a `vector` at the end.
- `a[] <-` is a way to do calcs on its *values* where the calcs do not preserve the "dimensionality" of the object.
- After we've rearranged, we then `t`ranspose back to the original shape and row/column-order.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R one-liner

```
> t(`dim<-`(t(a)[seq_along(a)%%length(a)+1],rev(dim(a))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    7    8    9   10   11
[3,]   12   13   14   15   16
[4,]   17   18   19   20   21
[5,]   22   23   24   25    1
```